# Nginx + SSL + Rails + Juggernaut (Node.js) + Engineyard

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, websocket, haproxy

I have two different applications on the same server. One of them is running on the 80 port (mydomain.com), another on the port 443 (sub.mydomain.com) and has wildcard certificate.

The first application is only for information purposes and don't need websockets support.
The second application should have secure websockets support (wss protocol).

I tried to set up juggernaut gem (for websockets) for my rails app with nginx server on the engineyard cloud, but i have one problem. Engineyard cloud provide only two opened ports: 80 and 443. I know that nginx do not fully support http 1.1 reverse proxing, so i can't use proxing from nginx for redirects websockets requests to the specific local port (in my case this port is 8080).

I tried use HAProxy and it's work for me when i use only unsecure websockets, but i need to support secure websockets. As i know in this case i should use something like STunnel for tunneling my https request and than use HAProxy, but when i test it - i saw that the server has to work several times slower and i still did not work to use the secure socket connection :(

Maybe I'm doing something wrong? Maybe someone will tell how to set up nginx for multiple applications (one of them should work via https) and secure websockets using only two ports (80 and 443).

p.s. Also i used a node-http-proxy, in this case i was able to set up proxy for different nginx applications but i do not get run websockets (happened only for "handshake" via nginx, not for "switching protocols")

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how to solve your problem (sorry), but I *can* recommend asking this question on ServerFault (and maybe SuperUser), as those crowds might be better equipped to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I did some research on the various reverse proxies and websockets not too long ago.  The bottom line is that websockets is new, and the reverse proxy support for it is very poor right now.

The recommendation I saw and I agree with is that you should run your websockets on a different stack than the rest of your items.  That usually means putting it on a separate domain or subdomain.

You still have to deal with the complexities of getting the reverse proxies working, but it will be less complicated if you don't have to worry about breaking the other stuff.

Also, I agree that maybe you'll get better answers at serverfault or superuser.